# Extract Multiline Data from a HTML site using Python

Tags: python, html, regex, multiline

So I've had great success extracting data as long as the what I'm matching doesn't cross more than 1 line, if it crosses more than 1 line I have heartburn (seemingly)... Here's a snippet of the HTML data I get:

```
<tr>
<td width=20%>3 month
<td width=1% class=bar>
&nbsp;
<td width=1% nowrap class="value chg">+10.03%
<td width=54% class=bar>
<table width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=barChart>
<tr>
```

I am interested in the "+10.03%" number and

```
<td width=20%>3 month
```

is the pattern that lets me know that the "+10.03%" is what I want.

So I've got this so far in Python:

```
percent = re.search('<td width=20%>3 month\r\n<td width=1% class=bar>\r\n&nbsp;\r\n<td width=1% nowrap class="value chg">(.*?)', content)
```

where the variable content has all the html code I'm searching. This doesn't seem to work for me... any advice would be greatly appreciated! I've read a couple other posts that talk about re.compile() and re.multiline() but I haven't any luck with them mostly because I don't understand how they work I guess...

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html. It will always end in heartache.

Comment: Do not use regex to parse HTML. Its a bad idea, because it can get complicated very quickly. Use something like [`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html).

Comment: So I tried HTMLParser but BeautifulSoup seems to work better... (HTMLParser returned a bad tags error) but I'm a little confused on how to get it to search for my 10.03% number.. do I search for <td width=20%> thats followed by "3 months" and then look a certain ways down for my 10.03%? How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked into lxml, which is one of the most popular python xml parser. It has intuitive xpath, and tree element model that makes iterating through xml and its elements quite easy and maintainable. [http://lxml.de/ ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help! You pointed me in the right direction, here's how I got my code to work with BeautifulSoup. I noticed that all the data I wanted was under a class called "value chg" followed by  and my data is always the 3rd and 5th element in that search, so this is what I did:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

content = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(content))

td_list = soup.findAll('td', {'class':'value chg'} )

mon3 = td_list[2].text.encode('ascii','ignore')
yr1 = td_list[4].text.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Again, "content" is the HTML that I've downloaded..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "multiline" regex switch `(?m)`. You can directly extract the target content using `findall` and taking the first element of the match via `findall(regex, content)[0]`:

```
percent = re.findall(r'(?m)<td width=20%>3 month\s*<td width=1% class=bar>\s*&nbsp;\s*<td width=1% nowrap class="value chg">(\S+)', content)[0]
```

By using `\s*` to match newlines, the regex is compatible with both unix and windows style line terminators.

---

See a [live demo](http://codepad.org/jIw890IE) of the following test code:

```
import re
content = '<tr>\n<td width=20%>3 month\n<td width=1% class=bar>\n&nbsp;\n<td width=1% nowrap class="value chg">+10.03%\n<td width=54% class=bar>\n<table width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=barChart>\n<tr>'        
percent = re.findall(r'(?m)<td width=20%>3 month\s*<td width=1% class=bar>\s*&nbsp;\s*<td width=1% nowrap class="value chg">(\S+)', content)[0]
print(percent)
```

Output:

```
+10.03%
```